# Ruby + Youtube Data API v3 Getting video info slow

Tags: ruby, json, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to get some info from a youtube video (title, description, thumbnail). I got it working but it's very slow (like 5 seconds) and I feel like I'm going about it all wrong. Is there a faster way than what I'm doing below?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

video = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=&part=snippet'
text = open(video) { |io| io.read }

hash = JSON.parse text

puts hash["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think the speed has nothing to do with ruby, but maybe your network connection or Google API.

As for your Code, I think I would do the same, or similar:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

video = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=&part=snippet'
hash = JSON.parse(open(video).read)

puts hash["items"][0]["snippet"]["description"]
```

If you're doing a lot of API stuff, I can highly suggest the [HTTParty gem](http://johnnunemaker.com/httparty/)!